# Unit test class reference issue in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, xctest, multitargeting

I am working on multi target ios project in objective C. Some swift classes are also there by Bridging-header. There is a Unit test target for main target as Host application. I have to do unit test for another particular target [Say, SecondaryTarget]. I have added the "Unit test target" by Edit Scheme > Test to enable unit test.
I am trying to import a existing class and do the unit test. But I am always getting reference issue [file not found] in test classes, while importing the classes.

Comment: So is the project a workspace, and the secondary target a framework? Are you working in a single unit test target, or did you create a second one for SecondaryTarget?

Comment: @JonReid: Yes, I am using Cocoapods in my project. Secondary target is not a framework. Different targets are there for different customers. There is single Test target only. Need to do unit test for a single target [single customer].

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can't reuse the same test target against different apps. Instead, create a test target for each app. Share whatever test code you want across each test target.